# Jquery fadeOut not animating

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Can anyone see why this code doesn't display the animation? I can see in Chrome that the animation is happening correctly (in the F12 tools I see the animation happening, and the divs are switching in and out). So the code is working, but I am not seeing the main image animate - it is just disappearing when the remove() is called, and the next image is shown immediately when that happens.

I have checked IE10 and Chrome and they both do the same thing. I also tried using animate('opacity') with the same result.

I can't see it but I am guessing it is something simple I am just missing because I have been looking at it too long!

Thanks for your help.

The script:

```
function fader(){
    $('#fader div:first').fadeOut(600,function() {
        $('#fader').append('<div class="faderitem">'+$('#fader div:first').html()+'</div>');
        $('#fader div:first').remove();
        setTimeout('fader()',6000);
    });
}
```

The CSS:

```
#fader {
    width:620px;
    height:620px;
    position:relative;
}
#fader div.faderitem {
    width:620px;
    height:620px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="fader">
    <div class="faderitem"><img src="/images/scroller/26-a.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="620" /></div>
    <div class="faderitem"><img src="/images/scroller/26-b.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="620" /></div>
    <div class="faderitem"><img src="/images/scroller/26-c.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="620" /></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I've never seen passing in the function as a string to the setTimeout. Are you sure that works? I would do it as `setTimeout(fader,6000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because of the z-index. You see, you animate the first child of fader wich is behind the other ones.

Simply add those css, it should work after :

```
#fader.faderitem:nth-child(1){
    z-index : 2
}
#fader.faderitem:nth-child(2){
    z-index : 1
}
```

Edit : As Owen Masback mentionned, the good way to set a timeout is like that : `setTimeout(fader,6000);`

Comment: Thanks.I made my function this and it's all good now.

`function fader(){

 $('#fader div.faderitem:nth-child(1)').css('z-index',2);

 $('#fader div.faderitem:nth-child(2)').css('z-index',1);

 $('#fader div:first').fadeOut(2000,function() {
  $('#fader').append('<div class="faderitem">'+$('#fader div:first').html()+'</div>');
  $('#fader div:first').remove();
  setTimeout(fader,6000);
 });
    }`